# What issues will I encounter if the new /shop section of my website is HTTPS

Tags: seo, google-search-console, https

I am about to launch a new section of my website which is a small store for gift vouchers and a few branding products. My site is well ranked/positioned in Google organically and paid. However, for security reasons I would like to switch to HTTPS for the /shop section whereas the rest of my site for now remain in HTTP.

Do have have to create a separate site in Google webmaster tools or can I still nest the new section under my current site ?

Comment: I would recommend going with HTTPS for your entire site.   You are going to have the certificate and server that can handle it anyway.   It is usually easier to configure the entire site for HTTPS than just a part.   Moving from HTTP to HTTPS may cause a temporary drop in Google rankings, but when done with 301 redirects, most sites are back on track within a couple months.

Comment: Thank you for your response - It's very much appreciated! I can't migrate all of the site just yet to HTTPS and probably wont be able to until the new year due to time restraints. However, I am launching a small store on our website in the coming weeks to help boost our xmas sales and thus face the issue of keeping it HTTP like the rest of the site now or force the /shop section to HTTPS for peace of mind for the buyers. But if I understand correctly on google search console & analytics my site is http//:www.example.com, so with https://www.example.com/shop I need to create a new site ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a new site including `https` within Google Search Console. Here's an awesome (and new) article on [adding properties to GSC](http://searchengineland.com/seo-101-url-versions-add-google-search-console-282463)

Comment: Great article thank you! That has pretty much answered all of my questions :)